# Is vim.fn.winrestview supposed to restore the view saved with vim.fn.winsaveview?

Tags: neovim, lua

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57337515/4476484) (quoted below), I wanted to make a similar mapping using Lua.

> `nnoremap <expr> * v:count ? '*' : '<Cmd>silent keepjumps normal! *<CR><Cmd>call winrestview(' .. string(winsaveview()) .. ')<CR>'`

However, I tried the code below and it didn't work.

```lua
vim.keymap.set('n', '*',
    function()
         -- execute * normally if a count was supplied
        if vim.v.count > 0 then
            return '*'
        end

        -- save current window view
        local windowView = vim.fn.winsaveview()

        -- execute normal *
        vim.api.nvim_feedkeys('*', 'n', false)
        -- NOTE: vim.cmd([[silent keepjumps normal! *<CR>]]) doesn't work here*

        -- reset the window
        vim.fn.winresetview(windowView)

        return ''
    end,
    { expr = true }
)
```

** Executing a normal command from within a keymap callback doesn't work I guess. I get an error saying `E5108: Error executing lua: vim/_editor.lua:0: nvim_exec2(): Vim(normal):E523: Not allowed here`*

When I used the above code, the window was not restored and the cursor just jumped to the next instance of the word.

Did I miss something about the `vim.fn.winrestview()` function? Shouldn't it restore my cursor position?

Comment: The `normal` command is not allowed inside expression-mappings. I think that is your `feedkeys()` call.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. What about my `feedkeys()` call?

Comment: Oh, `normal` isn't allowed _specifically when `expr = true`_. I changed the mapping to not use `expr = true` and the `normal` command is allowed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `vim.fn.winsaveview()` and `vim.fn.winrestview()` functions are being used correctly.

The issue is that you can't use normal commands inside of a mapping callback when `expr = true` (read [`:help map-expression`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/map.html#%3Amap-expression) for more details).

Here is a solution:

```lua
vim.keymap.set('n', '*',
    function()
        -- if a count was supplied, execute * normally and exit
        if vim.v.count > 0 then
            vim.cmd('normal! ' .. vim.v.count .. '*<CR>')
            return
        end

        -- save current window view
        local windowView = vim.fn.winsaveview()

        -- execute * normally
        vim.cmd('silent keepjumps normal! *<CR>')

        -- restore the window view
        if windowView ~= nil then
            vim.fn.winrestview(windowView)
        end
    end
)
```